# DB2 date comparison

Tags: sql, date, db2, where-clause

I'm trying to query a DB2 database to find records between two date columns, `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` (dates are stored in YYYYMMDD format in DB). This is what I have but it's not working. Could anyone please help me fix this?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TBDeals
WHERE TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(START_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') >= '2020-03-01' 
  AND TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(END_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '2020-04-20';
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing dates as strings, which is not a good practice. On the other hand, the format that you are using does allow proper sorting, so why not simply check the existing values against strings, like so?

```
where startdate >= '20200301' and end_date <= '20200420'
```

The upside of this approach is that it can take advantage of indexes on the string dates columns.

If the values are numbers, then:

```
where startdate >= 20200301 and end_date <= 20200420
```

Comment: Actually, we are storing Start and End date as INT. That's the reason, I'm running into this trouble. When I put a comparison, naturally comparison fails.

Comment: @sravan: ... unless you compare them against numbers. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. Without conversion itself it was working. I messed up my query when I first ran it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your date range is backwards, try this version:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBDeals 
WHERE
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(START_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') >= '2020-03-20' AND
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(END_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '2020-04-01';
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. Let me fix that. But the issue still exists.